# ` key only registers when held down. ex: `````````

Tags: keyboard, windows-registry

After using sharpkeys which edits the registry, and attempting to restore to default, the ` key now only registers a press when held down ie. ``````````. Mapping the key to another key produces the same result, so it is not a hardware issue. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting the Keybindings**

To reset all the keys to normal state.

> Delete all of the settings in it
>   
>   Write to Registry

Then Reboot.
https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/wiki/Reseting-Keybindings

Comment: i tried exactly this process in my "attempting to restore to default". it didn't work and my problem is still there